# Pandas pivot and create extra columns for duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

So I have some data with duplicate index's and what I want as columns. example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                "id":[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                "contact_type":["email","phone","phone","email","mobile","email","phone","mobile"],
                "contact":["a@a.ca","123","456","b@b.com","78432","c@c.ca","12","12"]
                })
```

what I'm trying to do is make it so each ID is a single row. My ideal output would be

```
ID    email      phone      phone.1    mobile
1     a@a.ca     123        456        NaN
2     b@b.com    NaN        NaN        78432
3     c@c.ca     12         NaN        12
```

Trying to use df.pivot("id","contact_type","contact") gives me an error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". Problem is it doesn't seem to like that ID 1 has 2 phone's in contact_type. So is there another way I can go to get the data into this format?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assemble the final dataframe piece by piece (`pd.concat`), as you don't know in advance, how many different phone numbers an ID may have at the most. Assuming each ID has at most only 1 email or mobile number:

```
In [130]:

df_mail = df.ix[df.contact_type=='email', ['contact', 'id']].set_index('id')
In [131]:

df_mobile = df.ix[df.contact_type=='mobile', ['contact', 'id']].set_index('id')
In [132]:

df_phone = df.ix[df.contact_type=='phone', ['contact', 'id']]
In [133]:
# make a columns stores 'phone0', 'phone1' and so on:
df_phone['field'] = 'Phone' + df_phone.groupby('id').transform(lambda x: range(len(x))).contact.map(str)
In [134]:

df_phone = df_phone.pivot('id', 'field', 'contact')
In [135]:

df_mail.columns = ['Email']
df_mobile.columns = ['Mobile']
In [136]:

print pd.concat((df_mail, df_phone, df_mobile), axis=1)
      Email Phone0 Phone1 Mobile
id                              
1    a@a.ca    123    456    NaN
2   b@b.com    NaN    NaN  78432
3    c@c.ca     12    NaN     12
```